# Is WDC WD40PURZ different from WDC WD40PURZ-85

Tags: hard-drive

We had an HDD failure yesterday in our main CCTV Room. We were planning on purchasing a replacement for the damaged HDD. Unfortunately, during our search, a vendor mentioned that WDC WD40PURZ-85 4TB Purple differs from WDC WD40PURZ 4TB Purple. I want to ask whether this is true.

Distributors/vendors in our location don't have any spare WDC WD40PURZ-85 4TB Purple so we tried Amazon but Amazon only shows WDC WD40PURZ 4TB Purple (notice the missing 85). Is anybody familiar with this?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure it's not "WD40PURZ-85TTDY0" in both cases? That's what the full model number _usually_ looks like for WD. What does your old HDD's sticker say?

Comment: Hi. The problem is I wasn't permitted to check the physical HDD in our server room. I only referred for the model in the dashboard which is WD40PURZ-85. Amazon on the other hand only shows WD40PURZ so I don't know whether it is the same product/model

Comment: The only information I can find on the -85 version is at https://bizpartner.panasonic.net/public/system/files/files/fields/field_file/psd/2021/04/28/HDD_compatibility%2828_Apr_2021%29_1619600777.079.pdf which says 'The difference between "-74" and "-85" depends on the WD sales route' could simply be that it's the difference in bulk purchasing and low quantity.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

WD disks do not actually have model numbers that would look like "WD40PURZ-85". It sounds like your HDD reports itself as "`WDC WD40PURZ-85xxxxx`" via ATA, but either the NVR device's OS or its dashboard truncates it to 15 characters.

All WD HDD model numbers are either just "WD40PURZ" (what WD uses as the 'part number') or "WD40PURZ-85TTDY0" (what the HDD itself reports). Only the first part, `WD40PURZ` or `WD10EZEX`, is the actual "model number" that defines all the capabilities, so any product labelled WD40PURZ should be equivalent to any other WD40PURZ – a 3.5″ 4TB CMR HDD with [the same specifications](https://www.bhphotovideo.com/lit_files/487654.pdf). The part after the dash is usually irrelevant and most product summaries don't include it.